# Sword wielding monk book

Tags: story-identification, novel

I remember there is a monk character, and near the beginning he gets wounded fairly bad and has to meditate to heal himself. I believe he doesn't know what he is supposed to do, but gets a sign to continue. He also fights without weapons. He may speak to spirits but I don't remember.

Later in the story he and a group have to steal an artifact (getting fuzzy) that turns out to be a sword that he takes and kills the last antagonist of the book with.

I read it in 2013; the monk was one of a few different characters; it was the first of a trilogy; it was definitely more eastern style, martial arts monk.I am fairly sure the sword was special in some regard (enchanted, magical, or the like).

Comment: Anything else you can remember about th's book? [This](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) could help.

Comment: Do you remember what the religion was like? More western or eastern?

Comment: I may be waaaay off here but could they be the "monks" in the Trudi Canavan books (google them, you'll see the covers)

Comment: [This person on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fantasy/comments/5u8v3m/books_about_monks/?utm_source=amp&utm_medium=comment_list) appears to be searching for the same book.